The emulator process has terminated (having enough Storage)
Android Emulator issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated while having enough storage virtualization has already enabled through BIOS
Changing BIOS setting uninstall and then re-install the android studio

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
